# Virtualbox installation window is too small to see the buttons

Tags: virtualbox

When i try to install ElementaryOs 6b2 in a VirtualBox VM, i only see a part of the installation screen.
So it's not possible for me to see the buttons to go to the next configuration screens.

Do you know how it's possible to modify the default screen size (during installation)?

Thanks for your help,

Ange.

[image: installation screen capture]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gyuszi Kovács for your answer, it was the checkbox i was missing !!!
It now works perfectly. Thanks again for your help !!!!!!! Ange.

Comment: You are welcome, Ange. Please accept my answer as the correct one so that the question can be marked as resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Please open the configuration of the VM, go to Settings - System - Motherboard - Extended Features, and make sure "Enable EFI" is selected. Apply the setting and start the VM, the resolution should increase and you should be able to install eOS6 beta.

Comment: Thanks Gyuszi, I had the same issue, but your solution worked!