# 6.0 beta 2 - installation gui not completely visible in virtualbox

Tags: install

Installing the new version 6 beta 2  in virtualbox does not show all the options in sceen.
You have to "guess" and use TAB and ENTER to move trough the next screen and hope you hit it right

Below an example during the installation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and enabling EFI on the system motherboard of the VM fixed it (as described here https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/28121/26547)